# Integrating Kal with my Navigation/TabBar App

Tags: ios6

I'm very new to iOS development so my objective-c terms may be a little off. I am currently creating an application that has a calendar app within one of my 5 tabBarViewControllers.

Overall Goal: To integrate a Kal calendar with a toolbar/navigation bar at the top of one of my tabBarviewcontrollers and be able to schedule events through a button on the toolbar, like the calendar app on the iphone. And Also have a navigation bar at the top of every tabBarViewController.

- There is an example application within the Kal folder I downloaded and it had the exact layout I wanted, just without the tabBar at the bottom. *

What I've Done: I created a new tabBar application, went to the storyboard and created 3  navigation controllers linked to the main tabBarViewController and I added Kal into my project, no problem. I then implemented the calendar view code into my secondViewController class.

The only code I have implemented into my project was within the viewDidLoad function in secondViewController.m after [super viewDidLoad];:

KalViewController *calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:calendar.view];

[self addChildViewController:calendar];

Problem: There is the smallest spacing between the calendar and the nav bar. Other than that, the interface looks the way I want. How would I go about fixing this spacing?

Comment: Im getting another problem...... Now I am trying to use the today toolbar button and it doesn't work correctly. The button is placed within my tabbarviewcontroller correctly but when I click the button, the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SecondViewController showAndSelectToday]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x927e6f0' pops up. I am wondering

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I think I just found my answer when typing this problem out. But please post anything you think I should refer to being a new but some-what experience C++ programmer